# How and when to properly use *this pointer and argument matching?

Tags: c++, dereference

When I go thru the code written by collegue, in certain place, they use:

```
this->doSomething(); //-->case A
doSomething(); //-->case B
```

In fact I'm not sure about the great usage of *this pointer...:(

Another question with argument matching:

```
obj.doOperation();  //-->case C
(&obj)->doOperation(); //-->case D
```

In fact both cases are performing the desired operation, is it simply a way to make the code look more complex?

What is your recommendation on the above two question? When is the appropriate time to use them and why?

Comment: Why this is tagged with C? What has the term "argument matching" to do here?

Comment: Of course you should always use the most complicated looking method :)

Comment: I like the remark: **simply** a way to make the code look more **complex** (bolds mine), or paraphrasing, "a simple way to write complex code." Wow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but a note that both fragments may do different things:

```
namespace B { void doSomething() {} }

struct A {    
    void f()
    {
        using B::doSomething;
        this->doSomething(); // call A::doSomething
        doSomething(); // calls B::doSomething
    }

    int a;
    void g(int a)
    {
        this->a = a; // assigns argument to member
    }

    A* operator & () { return this; }
    void doOperation() {}
    void doSomething() {}
};

void g(A &obj)
{
    obj.doOperation();  // calls A::doOperation directly
    (&obj)->doOperation(); // calls A::operator & first
}
```

Comment: And if you'd overloaded `operator->`, it would also call that in the second example!

Comment: The former is a possible argument against using `using`!

Comment: @Oli: "if you'd overloaded ..." no. It would be called if I'd write `obj->doOperation()`. "The former is a..." it's a very weak argument.

Comment: Good point on `operator->`.  Regarding `using`, I'd say it's a fairly canonical argument; cluttering up the local namespace which then leads to confusion, rather than explicit disambiguation (i.e. `B::doSomething()`).

Comment: @Oli: Agree in this situation, but not against using `using` in general.

Answer (score 3):

Cases B and C are always the appropriate way. Cases A and D are equivalent and do nothing different.

A few exceptions to that:

- If the class has an overloaded `operator&` that does surprising things, then case D could do something different that C. Actually having classes which do this is not recommended, since it would be confusing.
- If there is a local variable `doSomething` (or something else of that name in the local scope), then A would refer to a different `doSomething` than B. Again it isn't recommended to get yourself into such a situation, better give different names to different things.

Answer (score 1):

C and D are different. If `doOperation` is virtual, case D will perform the virtual call, case C will perform a non-virtual call if `obj` is not a reference. This assumes however that `operator&` and `operator->` have not been overloaded.

I tend to use A over B since there may be a local `doSomething` identifier. Inside template code, things may get worse (although I can't come with a precise example right now). It is a good habit to take.

Comment: "non-virtual call if obj is not a reference" &mdash; Hmmm.... Can there be a difference between virtual and non-virtual call if obj is not a reference? Isn't it get resolved to the same function?

Comment: @ybungalobill: nope. if `obj` is a variable of class `C`, `obj.doSomething()` will always resolve to `obj.C::doSomething()`. If `obj` is a reference, it will perform the virtual dispatch.

Comment: If obj is a variable, virtual call `(&obj)->doSomething()` will get resolved to the same function as the non-virtual call `obj.doSomething()`, but one call is virtual and the other is non-virtual I guess :)